# How Can I create a Downloadable Product?

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, product, products-management, downloadable

I would create a Magento downloadable (this should be just an exercise) but when I try to create a new product 'Downloadable Product' option doesn't appear in drop down. I've found this problem on various new installations.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System > Configuration > Catalog > Downloadable Product Options

Choose the right status for 'Order Item Status to Enable Downloads' and click Save Config.

Then you should see 'Downloadable product' as an option when you add a new product.

Answer (score 1):

Login as Admin and select `System → Configuration → Catalog → Downloadable Product Options`. Set the “Order Item Status to enable Downloads” to `Pending` and Save then `click` on the `Save` button.

[image]

Then go to the main menu at the top and click on `Catalog → Manage Products`

Then `click` on the `“Add New Product`” button.

Complete the info as you would a simple product, make sure that you add an INVENTORY QUANTITY, and set the item price to 0.00, this is very important, and make the item to be IN STOCK. Before you add the DOWNLOADABLE INFORMATION, click on the SAVE AND CONTINUE BUTTON, this will create the correct link ID’s for the product and the item you want to upload.

[image]

Once the save operation has completed click on the `DOWNLOADABLE INFORMATION` tab and then click the `Links` tab.

[image]

On the Title textbox type the name of the album that the song belongs, to this would be the same as the title of the product, e.g Artist Name - Album Name.

Now click on the ADD NEW ROW button to add the song title to be downloaded.

TITLE= Name of the song e.g. 01. Song Title, PRICE= The price of the song, leave all the other setting as default.

Then click on the File ... button to locate and upload the song, I suggest you zip the song before uploading it, just to compress the size.

Then click on the upload button and wait for the song to upload, it will be complete when there is no orange or red border around the song title. Once that is done click on the `SAVE AND CONTINUE BUTTON`.

The product is now correctly created and should be available for purchase. If you want them to hear a sample of the song, create a 30sec version of the song and upload it under Sample on the ... button next to the File upload option, Make sure that you click the `SAVE AND CONTINUE BUTTON` each time you upload a sample or a complete mp3 file or it will give you an error.

If you server host is running suPHP make sure that the `media → downloadable → directories` have `777` permission or you will get a nasty white screen with scrambled text.

Now simply do a test purchase to see if it has worked for you.

[**-->Source**](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/catalog/how_to_create_a_downloadable_product)

[**-->Other Reference**](https://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/downloadable-products)

Answer (score 0):

**1. How to create downloadable products Magento 2**

In order to create downloadable products Magento 2, please go to the admin panel > Product > Catalog
[image]

In the catalog > Hover “Add Product” > Download Product

[image]

In the product page => you can configure such setting as General, Content, images and videos, Search Engine Optimization, Related Products, Up-sells, Cross-sells, Customizable Options, Product in Website, Design, Schedule Design Update, Gift Options, Downloadable Information.
[image]

In the Prices section, choose “advanced pricing” to set a special price for the product.
[image]

In the advanced pricing, you can set
– Special Price
– From…To
– Cost
– Tier Price
– Manufacturer’s suggested Retail Price
– Display Actual Price
Likewise, in the inventory section you can choose “Advanced Inventory”. As you may know, with downloadable products usually it's not necessary to manage the stock of the product.
[image]

You can choose this tab in case you want to upload some samples for the item you are selling.
To add samples, click on ” Add link” > insert title and upload file.
[image]

In this tab, you can upload the downloadable file for the product.

- Title: Type the name of the item
- Price: Type a price added to the base one that you have set in price tab.
- Max.Downloads: add 0 to set no limit for download. Also, you can set the number of times that customer can download that product.
- Shareable:

In case you want to allow the product to be downloaded only by registered customers, set it to No

If you don’t want to allow the product to be downloaded by guest, set to Yes.
Then, Click Save Config to save new changes.

You can see the guideline to configure downdloadable products magento 2 here: [How to creat and configure downloadable products Magento 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt4Ow.jpg)

Comment: hi there, please consider removing your answer as this question was intended for magento 1 and your answer is for magento 2.